# Time complexity of inner for loop

Tags: time-complexity, computer-science

I have been trying to figure out how the get to the solution of this for loop but I cant seem to understand why the answer is what it is. I get stuck on the inner for loop, can someone help me break it down step by step and to get to the answer of the second for loop, line 2. THIS IS FOR REVIEW NOT HOMEWORK. I am just trying to understand the concept better.

```
 1: for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // Runs n+1 times
 2:     for (int j = n; j >= i; j--) { // Runs (n+2)+(n+1)+ n(n+1)/2 - 3 times
 3:         cout << i << “,” << j <<endl; // Runs (n+1) + n(n+1)/2 - 1 times
 4:     }
 5: }
```

I know the second line is simplified to n(n+1)/2 +2n, but I dont understand how to even get the (n+2)+(n+1)+ n(n+1)/2 - 3 first.

Comment: What's your source for this problem?

Comment: this was a question that was given and that was the solution the teacher gave us but I dont know how he got to that answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 1: for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // Runs n+1 times
```

This line does not run for n+1 times. Since it is `i < n` It runs for `n` times.

```
2:     for (int j = n; j >= i; j--) {
```

This line runs for `n - i + 1` times. Because it uses `>=` for comparison.

So if we write down the executions for `cout` , we get something like this:

```
1: n+1
2: n
3: n-1
...
...
n: 1
```

So what we need to do is simply add numbers up to `n+1`

which is `(n+1)(n+2)/2`

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    for (int j = n; j >= i; j--) {
        cout << "something" << endl;
    }
}
```

---

Lets see for the values of `i`, how many times the inner loop is run.

```
i=0 --> n
i=1 --> n-1
i=2 --> n-2
i=3 --> n-3
...
...
i=n-1 --> 1
```

Let us increase each element to `n` to have an upper bound

> 1 + 2 + 3 +....+ n-1 + n < [n + n + n + .... + n] = O(n^2)

---

Lets throw half of the first elements, and the other half decrease it to `n/2`. For a lower bound.

> 1 + 2 + 3 +....+ n-1 + n > [n/2 + n/2 + ... + n/2] = (n/2)*(n/2) = (n^2)/4 =  Ω(n^2)

---

Lower and Upper bounds are `Ω(n),  O(n)`, we can deduce it is actually `ϴ(n)`.

---

We could have done this immediately by noticing it is actually an **arithmetic sequence**.

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = (1+n)*(n-1)/2 = ϴ(n^2)
```

Comment: In the solution the teacher gave us this (n+2)+(n+1)+ n(n+1)/2 - 3 times for the inner loop, why is this answer different then the answers that I have been getting on here? I need to show the time complexity of each line. We leave it at that form he doesnt have us deduce it to 0(n).

Comment: @monkey the time complexity is `ϴ(n^2)`. Are you studying at high-school or a university ? it differs...

Comment: I am learning at a university but the answer that the instructor expects focuses more then just the highest order term. The instructor wants the full equation.

Comment: Can't help then besides telling you in both cases it's `ϴ(n^2)`. How he got that expression is beyond me.